# My 9 month old's sleep schedule gets mixed up

Tags: working-parents, night-time, daily-routine, first-time

I'm a working mom and my son gets watched by dad and grandparents when I'm at work and our nighttime routines are all different now. My son never goes to bed at the same time any more and it is always a struggle.

It started a few weeks ago when me and my husbands work schedules changed. Before the change, he was always asleep by 7-8 pm and up at 6-7 am. That was going on for 3 months before this. Now he goes to sleep late and wakes up all through the night. It also seems like he isn't getting an adequate amount of sleep, sometimes going to bed a 11pm and waking at 6am.

I don't believe its teething.

I did add a humidifier in the room just in case it was the change in weather and the dry heat might be affecting him.

Any advice for a new working mom? I need all the help I can get.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. Could you provide the details on what concerns you? Is he going to sleep to late, or waking too early, or not sleeping well? Are you concerned that the amount of sleep he's getting isn't enough? How long has this been going on, and how was his sleeping before you went back to work?

Comment: He goes to sleep late and wakes up all through the night. All so it seems like he isnt getting a adequate amount of sleep. Sometimes going to bed a 11pm and waking at 6am. It started a few weeks ago when me and my husbands work schedules changed. Before the schedule change he was always asleep by 7-8 pm and up at 6-7 am. That was going on for 3 months before this. I dont believe its teething. I did add a humidifier in the room just incase it was the change in weather and the dry heat might be affecting him.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clarification. I suggest moving your explanations from the comment section to the question itself. I feel this would nicely round up the question for other users, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [white noise machine](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000KUHFGM) They work wonders. We use the one with our girls and they love it.

I know they cost a lot but we've had ours for years now.

Answer (score 2):

We found a cradle swing extremely useful with both of ours, when they were overtired and really needed to sleep but couldn't get off to sleep.

White noise + swinging motion + dim moving lights + mobile + mum or dad nearby = baby hypnotism machine.

[image: Cradle swing]

Answer (score 2):

White noise machines are great, but in my experience the ROUTINE is what will make the difference.  You say he goes to bed at different times every night; that makes a routine very hard for him to get into, and if he cannot reliably predict what will happen (bath at 7, book at 7:30, lights out at 8) it makes it more difficult for him to settle down.  Can all the caregivers get together and agree to a solid nighttime schedule, and stick to it?  Once he knows that the routine starts like this, and will go on this long, and have these separate parts to it, he'll also know that "okay, after lights out, I go to sleep.  Got it." and hopefully he'll drop right off.  Believe me, he's no more excited about the lack of sleep than you are. :)